# How do I merge separate git repository into existing one

Tags: git

I have a project which has its main repository on Bitbucket (let us say this is version 1).
Someone else started working on this project and did so using his own local git repository. I now got his repository on stick. He did not branch or pull, but just created the project from 'scratch' with a new, fresh repo. Let us call this version 2.
Now, how do I put the repo of version 2 back into the repo of version 1. I am willing to sacrifice all intermediate commits if needed as long as I can keep both the final version 1 and version 2 states.

Comment: If you're looking to just merge the code without git metadata, then it's more question about the code and ways how to merge it (not git) and there's nothing about what language/framework it's written in.

Comment: @Radek not sure I get your meaning. I should have indicated I am not a git-literate. But I don't get why the language/framework is important to the question? Ideally I would like to keep the metadata, but if it is impossible or too complex, I am willing to sacrifice it.

Comment: Do you want to push to repo1 the `master` branch of version2 as a separate branch of repo1?

Comment: @Irineau That sounds about right, if needed I can always merge them later...right? How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally managed to get this sorted. My problem was I did not know I could define multiple remotes.
So I simply added the new repo (version 2) as a second remote, then pulled it into the old repo and committed. After removing the second remote it retained all history in the first.
In retrospect I should have done this the other way round (pulled in the old version into the new one) to maintain the correct history sequence. But that is just window dressing.